# Como mandarle el resultado de busqueda del componente header a componente dashboard en react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Tengo esta estructura de mi layout

```
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/header/header.jsx';

export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <Outlet />
        </>
    );
}
```

Dentro del header tengo una input que uso como barra de busqueda, despues el resultado de la busqueda quiero mandarla al componente dashboard este es mi componente de rutas

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from "./components/login/login";
import ErrorPage from "./components/error/error";
import Registro from './components/registro/registro';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/dashboard';
import Perfil from './components/perfil/perfil';
import Curso from './components/curso/curso';
import Layout from './Layout';
import Messages from './components/messages/messages';
import Categorias from './components/categorias/categorias';
import Kardex from './components/kardex/kardex.jsx';
import Ventas from './components/ventas/ventas';
import CrearCurso from './components/crear-curso/crear-curso';
import { RouteGuard } from './components/RouteGuard';

export default function Router() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Layout />} >
                <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
                <Route element={<RouteGuard sesion={true} />}>
                    <Route path='registrarse' element={<Registro />} />
                    <Route path='ingresar' element={<Login />} />
                </Route>
                <Route element={<RouteGuard sesion={false} />}>
                    <Route path='perfil/:userId' element={<Perfil />} />
                    <Route path='curso/:idCurso' element={<Curso />} />
                    <Route path="messages" element={<Messages />} />
                    <Route path="categorias" element={<Categorias />} />
                    <Route path="mis-cursos" element={<Kardex />} />
                    <Route path="ventas" element={<Ventas />} />
                    <Route path="crear-curso" element={<CrearCurso />} />
                </Route>
                <Route path='*' element={<ErrorPage />} />
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    );
}
```

Como le hago para enviar información del componente header, al componente dashboard?

versiones: react-router-dom = 6.8.1, react = 18.2.0

Comment: No tengo idea de React pero sería posible enviar información usando los parámetros del Router, creo que esta pregunta te puede ayudar [React Router Pass Param to Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898789/react-router-pass-param-to-component)